# How can I obtain the SSL key of a proxy?

Tags: java, ssl

I'm behind a corporate proxy and I'm trying to get boot (the Clojure building tool)  to work. I'm setting up the proxy via boot.j4l.ini like this:

```
- Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy-hostname> - Dhttp.proxyPort=8090
- Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy-hostname> -Dhttps.proxyPort=8090
```

That causes this error to happen when downloading boot.jar: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I assume it's the SSL cert for the proxy that is not trusted and not the final destination of the connection. I'm trying to generate a keystore to pass to the process with the SSL public key and certificate from the proxy,  but,  how do I obtain that? I tried using:

```
java InstallCert <proxy-hostname>:8090
```

But when starting the SSL handshake it complained that it couldn't do it,  probably because it got a plain text response.

How can I obtain the SSL key of the proxy server to trust it in the Java process for Boot?

Comment: You need the certificate, not just the public key.

Comment: Fixed.  InstallCert downloads both

Answer (score 0):

The java program `InstallCert` installs the certificate to `java-home/lib/security/jssecacerts`. As per the `JSSE` [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager), first the TrustManager will look for the trust store file declared in the system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`. If this property is not defined, it will then look at the `jssecacerts`.

In your case, since even after installing the cert to `jssecacerts`, the trust manager is refusing to accept SSL handshake, it probably indicates that it is either not finding the `jssecacerts` at the usual place or there is a different trust store defined by the system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`.

If you are indeed using a default system keystore at `java-home/lib/security/cacerts` and you want to import the server cert to the system keystore, please take a backup of the system keystore first and then extract the cert from `jssecacerts` and import it to `cacerts` using the following commands.

## Extract certificate from created jssecacerts keystore

keytool -exportcert -alias [host]-1 -keystore jssecacerts -storepass changeit -file [host].cer

## Import certificate into system keystore

keytool -importcert -alias [host] -keystore [path to system keystore] -storepass changeit -file [host].cer